# Angular development and using services into run app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, interceptor, angular-services

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand why i can't get my code works.

I have put a session check in the run method from  my main module, everything for the checking part works well but for some reasons when i try to launch the modal to reconnect the user, i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- loginModalService.
```

I have already check the following reasons:

The loginModalService.js is include as well as the template.
I have put `run(['$rootScope', '$window', "$location", "loginModalService",
        function ($rootScope, $location, $window, loginModalService) {` i order to prevent minification trouble.

I took the idea of launching the modal into the run method from this website:
[authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You have missplaced the dependancy

`run(['$rootScope', '$window', "$location", "loginModalService",
        function ($rootScope,  $window, $location, loginModalService) {`

Comment: as stated by @pankajparkar, the order of your dependencies must match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone after looking more precisely into the error display, i finally get what didn't work on my code.

I didn't came from the run method but from the service that i create. I indeed put a $scope, which is not allowed in service.

Answer (score 0):

You have missplaced the dependancy

```
run(['$rootScope', '$window', "$location", "loginModalService",
        function ($rootScope,  $window, $location, loginModalService) {
```

Comment: do visit here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Because first i thought that it could be actually why it was not working, then i try and in fact it did change my problem

Comment: I didn't say such thing

Comment: @Wiist U think you deleted which was added 16 hours ago

Comment: anyway the problem is still here and i got no good answer until now

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility is loginModelService service was never registered on your angular app.

Comment: The other reason didn't change my error. Still the same. What do you mean by registered in your app? I create the service, i join it by creating directly as a service of my app : app.service("loginModalService"). I include the file into the index.html